# Why does my correlation plot look like this in JASP?

Tags: correlation, scatter-plot

[image: correlation plot]

one variable is total of a score measured on likert scale, the other is a measure of strength of understanding of a separate variable , with 4 being the strongest. Please help!

I am using JASP and have tried switching from scale to ordinal, and also tried a log transformation.